# how to unzip file from objective-c ios 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9, unzip

How i Can unzip File from objective-c  in ios 8 or ios 9  , i Use [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) and another framework but not work show "Build Projectname Failed "   , but not Show error or warning  .

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: Probably you are missing some configuration. That's the reason you're getting this error. Double check the steps (if available) to setup ZipArchive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library:

[1.SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)

And then you can unzip using this code

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/ImagesFolder"];

NSString *zipPath = Your zip file path;

[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The link to SSZipArchive in this answer is actually pointing to the same library included in the question, but called ZipArchive in the question. SSZipArchive is based on ZipArchive. SSZipArchive should be consistent about how it refers to itself. sigh...